# jQuery AJAX: Update [LastVisitDate] Field on POST?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

I have the below Login JavaScript for my MVC4 Application. I am attempting to add a value with my POST data to update the `[LastVisitDate]` each time a user logs in. However, whenever I login with my credentials, the value is still shown as `4/18/2014 10:04:47 AM`. I have verified my cache has been cleared and am at a loss as to what I may be doing wrong.

Anyone have some thoughts on the matter?

```
function login()
{
    var userName = $("#username").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    var rememberme = $("#rememberMe").is(':checked');
    // NEWLY ADDED
    var datestamp = Date.now();

    var data =
        {
            Email: userName,
            Password: password,
            RememberMe: rememberme,
            // NEWLY ADDED
            LastVisitDate: datestamp
        };

    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "/Account/Login",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#loginAlert").remove();
            if (data.returnUrl != undefined) {
                window.location.href(data.returnUrl);
            }
            else {
                window.location.reload();
            }         

        },
        error: function (result) {
            if ($("loginAlert").length() == 0) {
                var errorMsg = 'There was an error.';
                $("#navBar").after(errorMsg);
           } 
        }
    });
}

function EnterKeyPressed () {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        login();
    }
}

function closeAlert() {
    $("#loginAlert").alert("close");
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the issue is with your JavaScript code and not with the server side?

Comment: I'm still getting the hang of AJAX, so that could be a possibility. I had assumed since the rest was working I just had to designate the other field within my `DATA` section.

Comment: This looks right, so I suggest that you recheck your server side.

Answer (score 0):

You have just posted the Ajax code and there is no clear information on what is going on in the background.
But based on your question I am assuming you are not returning the last logged in date. If its a SQL query then you need to perform a Order by date DESC. See if it helps :)